# Post an OpenGraph action for Like and Comment without using Like and Comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, photo, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I am using **GraphAPI** to send **comments** and **likes** to a **facebook photo** from my site. The problem is I want to post the action to the user's wall, one which should be viewable from their friends' news feeds like *"ChrisB liked a link"* and *"ChrisB commented on a link"*, where link is the **photo's url on facebook**. Of course I expect the photo thumb and name and description to appear on the post as well.

I have attempted to use custom OpenGraph actions and objects for these, but **og:url won't accept facebook links now** (which is odd because it still works for facebook pages). The error I'm getting from the linter is *"Facebook urls cannot be crawled".*

Is there any way to get the result that I want?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Facebook URL directly, try using bit.ly links or some way of automating the redirection from your site to Facebook. For example, [I would](http://www.webniraj.com/2011/09/06/using-htaccess-files-to-hide-query-variables/) use the apache module `mod_rewrite` to create a page on my website, but have it redirect to Facebook.

E.g. 'fake page' would be domain.com/{photo_id}.jpg, but have `mod_rewrite` redirect to `http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={photo_id}`

Comment: But specifying an og:url does two things: (1) tells fb to scrape metadata from that link and (2) use that link on the post. I see how redirection can help with the second case but not the first, since its eventually going to end up scraping the facebook link anyway.

Comment: Its more to trick facebook into scraping its own page, to get past the error you're having.

Comment: The error "Facebook urls cannot be crawled" persists even with the redirect.

Comment: Dam. The last option is to read the contents of the page from facebook, e.g. using `echo file_get_contents($url);`. But it may be quite inefficient if you get lots of traffic.